# C++ lifetime of temporaries - is this safe?

Tags: c++, c++11

If I understand the rules for the lifetime of temporaries correctly, this code should be safe since the lifetime of the temporary `stringstream` in `make_string()` lasts until the end of the complete expression. I'm not 100% confident there's not a subtle problem here though, can anyone confirm if this usage pattern is safe? It appears to work fine in clang and [gcc](http://ideone.com/C0uMc3).

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

ostringstream& make_string_impl(ostringstream&& s) { return s; }

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
ostringstream& make_string_impl(ostringstream&& s, T&& t, Ts&&... ts) {
    s << t;
    return make_string_impl(std::move(s), std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
}

template<typename... Ts>
string make_string(Ts&&... ts) {
    return make_string_impl(ostringstream{}, std::forward<Ts>(ts)...).str();
}

int main() {
    cout << make_string("Hello, ", 5, " World!", '\n', 10.0, "\n0x", hex, 15, "\n");
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like it should be fine.

Comment: Technically it's OK but I believe you will find that it's rather inefficient. Consider just defining a string builder with an `operator<<`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Depends how aggressively the compiler inlines.

Comment: @cdhowie: No, I was thinking of the `stringstream`. Which should be an `ostringstream` but that won't help. The problem is it's so very general with locale support and all that, so, it's usually slooow.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Fair enough. Though if you're wanting to build strings from numbers and such (as in this example) you need something to do the conversion for you. I guess it depends on your use case.

Comment: In the situations where I'd use something like this particular helper I wouldn't be too worried about performance but I'm mainly interested in if the general pattern is safe and this is a simple example :)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf good point that it should be an ostringstream, will fix it.

Comment: This would work but for the sake of readability I'd be inclined to use the following in `make_string()`: `ostringstream s; make_string_impl(s, ts...); return s.str();`. It's not as clever, but it lets you use `ostringstream&` in your `make_string_impl()`, which means you can omit the `std::move()` nastiness -- just pass around a reference instead. And then `make_string_impl()` can return `void`, too. Easier to read, easier for the compiler to inline. It also side-steps your question about the safety of this technique.

Comment: @cdhowie For my own code, I find increasingly I prefer a pretty terse style and eliminating named temporaries wherever possible so this kind of pattern has popped up in a few places recently and I wasn't sure how safe it is. If the code had to be maintained by others I might opt for the more long winded version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The relevant part of the standard is in `§12.2`:

> 12.2.3) Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step
>   in evaluating the full-expression (1.9) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created.

Except:

> 12.2.4) There are two contexts in which temporaries are destroyed at a different point than the end of the full-expression. The first context is when a default construct is called to initialize an element of an array. ... [**doesn't apply**]
>
> 12.2.5) The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary. The temporary to which the reference is bound or the temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound persists for the lifetime of the reference except:
>
> - ...
> - A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call (5.2.2) persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the call.

So there you go. The temporary `stringstream{}` is bound to a reference in a function call, so it persists until the completion of the expression. This is safe.